# Trying to add a planity booking module inside an angular app component

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm making a web app in angular and i'm trying to integrate a booking module inside provided by the company who made the module.
this is the code they game me:

```
<script>
    window.planity = {
        key: 'myapikey',
        primaryColor: '$primaryColor'
    };
</script>
<script src="https://d2skjte8udjqxw.cloudfront.net/widget/production/polyfills.latest.js"></script>
<script src="https://d2skjte8udjqxw.cloudfront.net/widget/production/app.latest.js"></script>
```

so i loaded both of the script in the index.html of my app and this is the code in my components so far:

**typescript:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { LayoutService } from '../../_metronic/layout';

type Tabs = 'Header' | 'Toolbar' | 'PageTitle' | 'Aside' | 'Content' | 'Footer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-appointment',
  templateUrl: './appointment.component.html',
})
export class AppointmentComponent implements OnInit {
  activeTab: Tabs = 'Header';
  model: any;
  @ViewChild('form', { static: true }) form: NgForm;
  configLoading: boolean = false;
  resetLoading: boolean = false;
  
  constructor(private layout: LayoutService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.model = this.layout.getConfig();
    this.initializePlanity(); // Initializing the Planity object
  }

  initializePlanity(): void {
    console.log("Initializing Planity...");
    (window as any).planity = {
      key: 'myapikey',
      primaryColor: '$primaryColor' // Replace with your desired color
    };
    console.log("Planity initialized:", (window as any).planity);
  }

  setActiveTab(tab: Tabs) {
    this.activeTab = tab;
  }

  resetPreview(): void {
    this.resetLoading = true;
    this.layout.refreshConfigToDefault();
  }

  submitPreview(): void {
    this.configLoading = true;
    this.layout.setConfig(this.model);
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body d-flex align-items-center py-8">
    <div id="planityContainer"></div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

But nothing is displayed on the page... no error in the console and the code is working inside a regular html page (and yes i checked the API key) is that the right way to do it? am I missing something?